# Can't redirect to another php page after I login, the login form reloades on the same page instead

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Recently I've been facing this problem for a couple days. The login validation works perfectly. Unfortunately, I can't redirect to another page which is `index.php` after I try to login, and the login form is reloading on the same page at the bottom of the form instead, which is supposed to be for the error message just in case the user inputted the wrong username or password. Here are the screenshots of the form:

[Screenshot of the login form at `login.php`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T4pn.png)

[Screenshot of the login form when the user doesn't fill all the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfzVz.png)

[Screenshot of the login form when the user inputted the wrong username or password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usmb6.png)

[Screenshot of the login form after the user inputted the correct username and password, the form is reloading on the same page. Instead, I want it to redirect to another page, which is `index.php`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHln0.png)

Here's my code:

**login.php**

```
<?php 
    require_once 'templates/header.php';
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/login-style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#login').click(function(){   
            var username = $('#usernameID').val();
            var password = $('#passwordID').val();

            $.post("classes/validation_login.php",{
                user_val : username,
                password_val : password,

            },function(data){
                if(data == 'success'){
                    window.location.href='index.php';
                }else{
                    $('.error-message').html(data);
                }
            });
        });

    });


</script>

<title>Login</title>
<form id="login-form">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" id="usernameID" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"> <br>

    <input type="password" id="passwordID" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"> <br>

    <input type="button" id="login" name="register-button" value="Login">

</form>

<div class="error-message">

</div>

<?php 
    require_once 'templates/footer.php';
?>
```

**validation_login.php**

```
<?php 

require_once '../core/init.php';

class validation_login{

    private $username,$password;
    public $errorMessage;

    public function validate_login(){
        $db = new database();
        $this->username = input::get('user_val');
        $this->password = input::get('password_val');

        if(empty($this->username) || empty($this->password)){
            $this->errorMessage = "Please fill all the fields!";
            return false;
        }else if(!$db->login()){
            $this->errorMessage = "Invalid username or password!";
            return false;
        }else{
            session::set('username',$this->username);
            return true;
        }
    }

}

$login = new validation_login;
$login->validate_login();
echo "$login->errorMessage";

?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's because you cannot redirect on the server side from an AJAX request. You will need to send the login result back to the client, then redirect there. Alternatively, if you want to redirect on the server, don't use AJAX.

Comment: response back your url in your ajax request and redirect from your success data like `window.location = data.redirect_url;`

Comment: I've updated my ajax code. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I still can't redirect to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You redirect within the ajax call. Thats the misstake.
Remove the AJAX call and add an action tag to the form. (to validation_login.php)

```
<form action="validate_login.php" method="post" id="login-form">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It is because you cannot redirect on the server side when using ajax, try returning a value and redirect base in the value, you can rewrite your code as below

validation_login.php

    <?php 

require_once '../core/init.php';

class validation_login{

    private $username,$password;
    public $errorMessage;

    public function validate_login(){
        $db = new database();
        $this->username = input::get('user_val');
        $this->password = input::get('password_val');

        if(empty($this->username) || empty($this->password)){
            $this->errorMessage = "Please fill all the fields!";

        }else if(!$db->login()){
            return false;

        }else{
            session::set('username',$this->username);
            return true;

        }
    }

}


?>

login.php



     <?php 
    require_once 'templates/header.php';
    ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/login-style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#login').click(function(){   
            var username = $('#usernameID').val();
            var password = $('#passwordID').val();

            $.post("classes/validation_login.php",{
                user_val : username,
                password_val : password,

            },function(data){
                if(data){
                 //means validation went through
                 //redirect user
                 window.location.href='index.php';


                 }else{
                 //validation returned false
                 //display error message
                     $('.error-message').html('incorrect Username or password');
                  }


            });
        });

    });


</script>

    <title>Login</title>
    <form id="login-form">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" id="usernameID" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"> <br>

    <input type="password" id="passwordID" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"> <br>

    <input type="button" id="login" name="register-button" value="Login">

</form>

<div class="error-message">

</div>

<?php 
    require_once 'templates/footer.php';
?>
```